# Zpanel output error: This domains disk limit has been exceeded?

Tags: apache, vps, vhosts, izpanel

Automatically zpanel showing This domains disk limit has been exceeded! for all the websites hosted in VPS with ZPanel

```
This domains disk limit has been exceeded!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this problem occurs but the solutions what I got

Edited `/etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Problem Caused Virtual Host Code

```
# DOMAIN: domain.in
# THIS DOMAIN HAS BEEN DISABLED FOR QUOTA OVERAGE
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName domain.in
ServerAlias domain.in www.domain.in
ServerAdmin admin@domain.in
DocumentRoot "/etc/zpanel/panel/etc/static/diskexceeded"
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtm
</virtualhost>
# END DOMAIN: domain.in
################################################################
```

**Replaced with**

```
################################################################
# DOMAIN: domain.in
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName domain.in
ServerAlias domain.in www.domain.in
ServerAdmin zadmin@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain_in"
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain_in:/var/zpanel/temp/"
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, show_source, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg, exec"
ErrorLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/cessindia.in-error.log" 
CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/cessindia.in-access.log" combined
CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/cessindia.in-bandwidth.log" common
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/_cgi-bin/"
<location /cgi-bin>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options ExecCGI
</location>
ErrorDocument 500 /_errorpages/500.html
ErrorDocument 403 /_errorpages/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /_errorpages/404.html
ErrorDocument 510 /_errorpages/510.html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtml

</virtualhost>
# END DOMAIN: domain.in
```

Answer (score 0):

Better Option:

1. SSH to the server,
2. type `service httpd restart`

That's it and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of Problem is happened under the zpanel control panel
first you have to change value of disk quota under the package manager "i.e 0 for unlimited" save it and then reload your apache, see the result